# reload compare editor input

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I have a CompareEditorInput shown in CompareEditor, it compares textual data. I need to reload CompareEditorInput when it is changed outside of CompareEditor.

1. Open compare editor (CompareUI.openCompareEditor(input))
2. Compare input is changed (ISteramContentAccessor.getContents() returns changed content)
3. Tell opened compare editor to reload CompareEditorInput <- needs to be implemented.

Comment: What happens if you call `setInput(sameInput)` on the editor part?

Comment: @MarttiKäärik, how can I find this compare editor? I open it with `CompareUI.openCompareEditor(input);` and I don't have its instance.

Comment: Use [`IWorkbenchPage`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/IWorkbenchPage.html)`.findEditor(IEditorInput input)`.

Comment: @MarttiKäärik, one more thing. There is a compiler warning stating that `CompareEditor` class is not intended to be used here when I use CompareEditor class directly, e.g. `CompareEditor compareEditor = (CompareEditor) editor;`. Are there less invasive way to call `setInput` method on the editor?

Comment: You don't need `CompareEditor`, `setInput()` is defined in [IEditorPart](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/IEditorPart.html).

Comment: @MarttiKäärik, no, there is not setInput declared in `IEditorPart` neither in its ancestors. `CompareEditor` overrides `setInput` from `EditorPart`. But it is protected in `EditorPart` and I can not call it from there.

Comment: Right, should have checked... You can try `init(IEditorSite site, IEditorInput input)`, it doesn't do much more than call `setInput()` in `CompareEditor`.

Comment: @MarttiKäärik, thanks, that worked! Could you suggest me a good book about eclipse rcp?

Comment: I haven't read any myself but you can ask on Stack Overflow ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could call `setInput(sameInput)` on `CompareEditor`, but since `CompareEditor` is internal and `setInput()` is not public in [`EditorPart`](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/part/EditorPart.html) then a workaround is to call [`IEditorPart`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/IEditorPart.html)`.init(IEditorSite site, IEditorInput input)`.

```
IWorkbenchWindow wnd = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
IEditorPart editor = wnd.getActivePage().findEditor(input);
editor.init((IEditorSite) editor.getSite(), input);
```

Comment: You are the man.. It's been 3 weeks of failure trying to get to do this on my own. I was about to modify the EditorPart implementation making setInput public and rejar it.

Answer (score -1):

The new java io package java.nio.file package provides a file change notification API, called the Watch Service API. using this you can monitor the file on the disk and track for any changes. Check this for further [reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html)

Create a separate thread which uses the WatchService API and monitors the file in the background and if finds any changes on disk, notify the user.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not right. Actually file is not changed. The loaded from file content is changed, file is not.

Comment: you mean to say that file content is changed outside your compare editor?

Comment: if I open the same file using your compare editor and textpad, and if I make any changes using textpad and save the changes, your compare editor should be able to track that file content has been changed? am i getting it right?

Comment: File content is not used here. I use IStreamContentAccessor to access contents that has to be compared. This looks the following way: load contents from file (the only time when file is accessed) -> file contents is stored in the instance of IStreamContentAccessor.

Comment: `your compare editor should be able to track that file content has been changed? am i getting it right.`
You are not right. File contents is not changed. Contents that are stored in IStreamContentAccessor are changed.